# Avaya JTAPI: How to get called number after call was established

Tags: avaya, jtapi

Using the Avaya implementation of JTAPI, I am trying to get the called number on a call that is already established. In other words the connection listener is registered on a call after it is established.

When I try using the CallControlCall.getCalledAddress() in this scenario it returns null, presumably because that details are populated by the connection listener?

Is there any other way of getting the called number after the fact?

Or is there a way of getting to a specific call object if I only have the extension and the number that was dialed, assuming that the extension might have multiple calls active, and that the call is already established when I start searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question for those who get a similar query in the future.

Avaya CM sends this information to the AES *only* during the setup of the call, there is therefor no way to get the called number when placing a monitor on the call after the call was made.

This came from an answer I received on the [Avaya DevConnect forums](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/forums/posts/list/0/20499.page#p147048).

Answer (score 1):

With JTapi is not possible get the caller number if you register on AES server at the middle of a call.

You can do it with ASAI protocol but you require the DLG port opened, and it is harder than JTapi.